# Mockito: How to get the state of an argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

The scenario is I am trying to validate a  domain object and store the validation messages in another object. The class is `Validator` and the method looks like:

```
public void validate (Domain domain, ValidationInfo info)
```

And the `ValidationInfo` object has:

```
List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String> messages ()
```

The `Validator` class is called from a service class. Whatever validation fails for the domain object the failure messages will be stored in the list in the `ValidationInfo` class.

In the service test class in one of the test case i wrote the following to test the validation failure:

```
@Test
public void testvalidation () throws Exception { 
    Domain domain = createDomainWithInvalidData();
    service.create (domain);
    verify(mockValidator).validate(domain, validationInfo);
    assertFalse (validationInfo.getMessages().isEmpty());
```

Now What I want is to get the failure messages from the `validationInfo` object so that I can write some asserts based on that. But it's not working.

Can anybody shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you are unit testing the **`service`**.

Actually there's is no point in getting the messages from `validationInfo` as it is passed to a method of **Mockito mock** which **does nothing by definition** unless you write a stub (`given(...).willReturn(...)`). Even the last assertion in your code sample is not necessary as validationInfo won't be modified by the  default mocked behavior of `validate`.

Mockito is designed and lead to test interactions between collaborators, which is already done with your verification `verify(...)`, as you are testing the service and his collaboration with the `Validator`.

Testing the message that was written in `ValidationInfo` has nothing to do with the scope of `service`

However what you want is to unit test the **`Validator`**, in which you should write specific tests for validation messages. Look at the following snippet where I imaginated some part of the `ValidationInfo` API :

```
public class ValidatorTest {

    Validator validator = new Validator(); // not a mock

    @Test
    public void when_<some_part_of_the_domain>_is_incorrect_report_validation_error() throws Exception { 
        // given
        Domain domain = createDomainWithInvalidData();

        // when
        validator.validate(domain, validationInfo);

        // then
        assertThat(validationInfo.getMessages()).isNotEmpty()); // not really necessary
        assertThat(validationInfo.getLastMessage().text()).contains("<some_part_of_the_domain> is wrong");
    }
}
```

Note that I used the **BDD** keywords (given, when, then) to help me write the test. Alos I used FestAssert library which affer great assertion tools.

Hoep that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Brice. You are right that I am actually testing the `service`. But just out of curiosity, is there a way to do what i asked earlier. If so how. I tried using `ArgumentCaptor` buts it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what i wanted after breaking my head for hours.

What we need to do is use `doAnswer` of mockito. Please find below the snippet:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<ValidationInfo> () {
  @Override
  public ValidationInfo answer (InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
     Object [] args = invocationOnMock.getArguments();
     ValidationInfo vi = (ValidationInfo) args [1];
     vi.getMessages.add("some message");
     return vi;
}}).when(validator).validate (domain, validationInfo);
```

This way I was able to put custom failure messages in the list which made the validation fail in the service; which was the whole purpose of the test.

And earlier the test was not passing because in the service code there was a check on the size of the list. And the list size was always zero as `verify` will just verify whether the method gets called or not but wont actually change the state of the object.

Hope this helps. If there is any better way of achieving this please comment.

Comment: You are overcomplicating yourself, plus the assertion `assertFalse (validationInfo.getMessages().isEmpty());` do not test your production code but that the answer you just wrote actually added some message. This behavior looks like it's what you expect from the validator, a behavior that should be tested in his own unit test. Anyway if your service should fail upon `validationInfo`, then you have to do that, or you could design differently your code, say `validatioInfo.addFrom(validator.validate(domain))` or if validator is an interface `validationInfo.validate(domain, validator1)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Brice for your inputs...Actually as you said, as the service fails upon `validationInfo` i had to do that. You are right that I could design it differently. I could make the `validate` method return `validationInfo`. Then I would be able to write a stub `when(...).thenReturn(...)`. Thanks again for your advice.